# PHP Form Data Not Copying To Database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$db1 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;
    dbname=jbdb;
    charset=utf8', 'myname', 'nicetrylol');

    //echo $_POST["username"]; test works
    $username =  $_POST["username"];
    $password =  $_POST["password"];
    $password1 = $_POST["password1"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];

    if ($password == $password1){

    $doit = "INSERT INTO 'users'('username', 'password', 'email') 
        VALUES
        (:username, :password, :email)";

    $query = $db1->prepare( $doit );
    $query->execute( array( ':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$password, ':email'=>$email ) );



    echo "The passwords match.";
```

}

There are no errors when I test the forms, and I receive the proper echo, but when I run "select * from users;" in the mysql console, it returns an empty set. Is there a syntactic error in my code?

I realize my code is not properly validated. This is just a test case as I learn the PDO syntax. I am running php 5.5 with the uniform server on a windows machine. There are four columns in the table, with id set to automatically increment.

Comment: How do you know there are no errors, when you don't check for any error values? Try to configure PDO to throw exceptions on error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't wrap your table name or columns in quotes:

```
$doit = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email)
```

Comment: and if you do do it with ` not with '